# On Mobile devices setTimeout() causing error

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, mobile

I am working on `form`, it is properly showing that "form is submitted" on desktop, and message hides after some seconds.

But on mobile it is not showing any message for submitted form.

Here is My code.

**HTML**

```
<p id="password_response_msgs" style="margin-left:40px; color:#F00"></p>
    <div class="row">
       <div class="col-sm-6 form-group">
          <form name="password_form" method="post">
             <label class="sr-only" for="userFirstName">Password</label>
             <input type="password" class="form-control" name="password" id="user_password" placeholder="password" value="<?php echo $row['password']?>">
       </div>
       <div class="col-sm-6 form-group">
              <label class="sr-only" for="userLastName">Confirm Password</label>
              <input type="password" class="form-control" name="confirm_password" id="user_confirm_password" placeholder="Confirm Password" value="">
      </div>
   </div>
   <div class="row">
       <div class="col-md-6">
          <a class="btn btn-block btn-primary" onClick="updatepassword();" style="color:#FFF">Update Password</a>
       </div>
   </div>
      </form>
```

**Javascript & Ajax**

```
function updatepassword(){
     var user_password = document.getElementById('user_password').value;
     var user_confirm_password = document.getElementById('user_confirm_password').value;
     if(user_password==''){
       document.getElementById('password_response_msgs').innerHTML = 'Please Enter Password';
     }else if(user_confirm_password==''){
        document.getElementById('password_response_msgs').innerHTML = 'Please Enter Confirm Passowrd';
     }else{
        $.ajax({
              url: "<?php echo BASE_URL;?>ajax/save-profile.php",
              data:{command:'updatepassword',password:user_password,user_confirm_password:user_confirm_password,user_id:<?php echo $user_id;?>},
              cache: false,
              success: function(res) {
                    document.getElementById('password_response_msgs').innerHTML = res;
                }
            });
   }
}
```

And i hides the message after some seconds in this way. This works on desktop, but not mobile devices. But if i delete the below code then message also shows on mobile devices.

```
  setTimeout(function() {
     $('#password_response_msgs').fadeOut('slow');
  }, 10000);
```

**why it is not working on mobile?**

Comment: What is the browser you are using on your mobile device?

Comment: @Jackyef chrome

Comment: Can you connect your phone to your PC/laptop, do a remote debugging session using desktop chrome and see if any error show up in the console?

Comment: Need some more information : Specific mobile browser ? May be low connection you don't have on desktop ?